# Need double c-g to quit from a minibuffer

Tags: key-bindings

On one of my devices I need double pressing `C-g` to quit from a minibuffer, even when no initialization file is loaded.

More specifically, after pressing `C-x C-f`, if I do not realease the control botton, I only need one `C-g` to quit the minibuffer. But if I realease, I need two.

If I only press `C-g` once, the minibuffer shows the text quit, but the cursor is still focused on the minibufer, and I have to press `C-g` again within 3 seconds, otherwise the Find-File minibuffer reappears after the text quit fades in 3 seconds. And in that case, I will need to double-press again to quit.

GNU Emacs 24.5.1 (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.20.6) of 2016-06-04 on juergen

EDIT:

I solved this by switching off the option of `Show position of pointer when the Control key is pressed` in Linux mouse setting. 
I guess there is some conflict between Emacs and this option.

Comment: Sounds like a bug, if, as you say, you see this with `emacs -Q` (no init file). Consider filing a bug report: `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: This only happens on one device?  What kind? Do you run emacs in the terminal?

Comment: If this happens reliably try setting 'debug on quit' to see what Emacs is actually quitting the first time. It will open a backtrace.

Comment: @Drew Reported.

Comment: @JeanPierre Only happens to my laptop, not in a terminal.

Comment: @YoungFrog No backtrace window pops up. I guess it is not even an error.

Comment: The proper way to mark a question as solved is to post an answer and accept it. You can answer your own question.

Comment: You can accept your own answer. That way, it does not show up in the list of unanswered questions. (But don't accept your answer if you still want/expect other answers.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this myself by switching off the option of `Show position of pointer when the Control key is pressed` in Linux mouse setting. I guess there is some conflict between Emacs and this option.

Comment: THANK YOU!!! By the way, did you report a bug for that?

Comment: No, I did not. Not sure to whom and where I should report. Maybe you can do that?